# Can I install Deepin Desktop Environment 2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, ppa, desktop-environments

I have tried to install Deepin DE from [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-13-04.html) . But it doesn't work. In this article they have used PPA from "raring ringtail." I want to install Deepin DE from trusty PPA. But I can't found the PPA.

Is there any PPA is available to install Deepin DE v2 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use the software lists just as described in the tutorial, all you have to do is change all instances of the word raring to trusty.

1. First, open the /etc/apt/sources.list file in an open terminal with the following command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Add the following lines:

   ```
   deb http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin trusty main non-free universe
   deb-src http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin trusty main non-free universe
   ```

   Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write changes to the file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the changes. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit from nano.
2. Now you need to import GPG key and install using the following three commands in an open terminal:

   ```
   wget http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin/project/deepin-keyring.gpg
   gpg --import deepin-keyring.gpg
   sudo gpg --export --armor 209088E7 | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Update your package list:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. You may now proceed with the remainder of the [tutorial](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-13-04.html) to install the desired packages.

---

Just to let you know, this is not how to install a "ppa". Installing a ppa essentially provides an alternative repo to your apt-get sources list. However, ppa(s) are provided through launchpad and are maintained by third parties. The method outlined above directly adds the repo to your /etc/apt/sources.list file instead. Normally, to add a ppa you would use the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository
```

followed by ppa: and the name of the ppa.

Noobslab maintains a third party ppa for Deepin but they are not affiliated with the Deepin project, and so I will not recommend that method, as there is already a direct method available to add the Deepin repositories without the use of a ppa.

[launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/deepin-sc](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/deepin-sc)

Comment: That GPG key adding there, it no longer works. It just gets Error 404 because it no longer exists on that URL directory. They've changed it to a new directory.

Comment: @user94959 actually, i just tried it and got a 404 but tried again and it worked so maybe try again if it doesn't work the first time