# apt- Error installing Deepin Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, desktop-environments

I have been trying to add the Deepin Desktop Environment to Ubuntu. I have followed several guides that consist of adding the sources etc and then trying

```
sudo apt-get install dde-meta-core
```

however it keeps returning the following error at the bottom

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 dde-meta-core : Depends: deepin-desktop-environment but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: dde-control-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed the below thread mostly, but have googled for a while now with no luck.

[Can i install Deepin Desktop Environment 2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515302/can-i-install-deepin-desktop-environment-2-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/532324#532324)

Im a recent Linux convert, so please excuse any stupid mistakes. 
Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Mixing other distribution repositories as the answer you refer is always a bad solution and will always end up bad. I suggest you to install the actual OS, either Deepin way is not supported here in Askubuntu.

Comment: check this answer, http://askubuntu.com/questions/761107/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/832985#832985

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, if you want to get a "Material" desktop, to use Paper GTK theme. I know it's Beta but I love it anyway.
There's a link with a step-by-step:
http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/Beautiful-New-Paper-Theme-Made-for-GNOME-and-GTK3-467854.shtml

If you want another icons search on the internet, or you can install the deepin icons with those repos you have, maybe on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install deepin-icon-theme
```

A package manager should work too, searching for the "deepin" software.

Hope it helps you.