# How to install Deepin Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, desktop-environments, 16.04

I want to install Deepin Desktop Environment on my Ubuntu Xenial. Can anyone provide a step by step walkthrough on what repositories to add and how to install? I couldn't find any comprehensive tutorial on how to do so on Xenial. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There is no official support in repository for Ubuntu 16.04

You can see it, if you click on the link https://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin/dists/

We'll have to install from source: https://github.com/linuxdeepin

Answer (score 4):

This is available at: https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dde
```

After installing, just logout and select the deepin environment. If you get a login loop, log into Unity again and change your GPU driver and you should be fine.

Comment: There's no release for xenial.

Comment: You can't install on ubuntu 16.04 becuase there is no release available. You will get this message "E: Unable to locate package dde"

Comment: The dde depends on qt version above than 5.6. If you want to install dde, you need to upgrade to 17.04 or above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the Deepin Repository to your Ubuntu or Ubuntu Derivatives

We need to add Deepin Repository in your Ubuntu or its derivative system. To do so, run the following commands in a shell or terminal:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxdeepin.list
deb http://packages.deepin.com/deepin trusty main non-free universe
deb-src http://packages.deepin.com/deepin trusty main non-free universe
EOF
```

For Ubuntu 17.10

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxdeepin.list
deb http://packages.deepin.com/ubuntu artfull main non-free universe
EOF
```

As I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr so, I have trusy in above command, if you are  running Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Tail based system, replace trusty with raring.

2. Download and import the public key

Now, we'll have to import the Deepin GPG key and install it by the following commands:

```
$ wget http://packages.deepin.com/deepin/project/deepin-keyring.gpg
$ gpg --import deepin-keyring.gpg
$ sudo gpg --export --armor 209088E7 | sudo apt-key add -
```

P.S. Previously, the link used to look like this: "packages.linuxdeepin.com", but later I found that it's only "packages.deepin.com" nowadays. Edited it for everyone's sake.

3. Update the source repository index

Now, we need to update our local repository index which has all the information and source url of the packages required to install.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

4. Install Deepin Desktop Environment

Finally, we need to install package called dde-meta-core which will download and will install all the Core Meta packages as well as dependencies which is required for your workable Deepin Desktop Environment.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dde-meta-core
```

Note: The above command will setup Deepin Desktop Environment and its core packages, but if you wanna install some exciting cool apps developed by Deepin Project like Deepin Software Center, Deepin Music Player, Deepin Games, Settings panel. please follow the below steps after the above step is done !

Deepin Packages :

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-deepin-gsettings deepin-music-player deepin-software-center deepin-movie deepin-game-center
```

[source](http://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-deepin-desktop-environment-derivatives-ubuntu/)

Comment: did anybody succsfully installed this on 16.40? I dont see packages for xenial on http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin/dists/ as of now

Comment: The reason why Xenial isn't available is because these are old packages from when Deepin was still based on Ubuntu (LTS), before it switched to Debian (Unstable) in December 2015.

Answer (score 0):

The above instructions is missing the most important step,

you may have to add/create file '/etc/apt/preferences' and change it content to the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Deepin
Pin-Priority: 9999

Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 400
```

Install to bluez 5

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

if you already have bluez installed you , it will replace the current v4.x with v5.x

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade bluez
```

Install the following dependencies packages

```
sudo apt-get install dde-daemon
sudo apt-get install dde-control-center
```

Make a whole check by using 'aptitude' to make sure packages which shown in both repository that come from 'deepin' repository instead of 'ubuntu' , [read more](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-installer/issues/6)

Downgrade `libglib`

```
sudo aptitude install libglib2.0-0=2.40.0-10~trusty
```