# How to install DDE on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, desktop-environments

I am trying to install Deepin Desktop Environment (DE) on Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried [This Thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761107/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but nothing seems to work for me and Deepin does not have any official documentation regarding this problem.

Comment: when you log out, are you able to select this desktop environ?

Comment: Basically I ma not able to install DDE (Deepin Desktop Environment) it says package not fount after adding the repos.